# How to highlight/change color to labels based on a group in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I'm plotting an N×N similarity matrix with imshow function. The keys variable are the labels of the graph. In another file, each key is associated to a group (example `A,B` = `group1`, `C` = `group2`, `E,F` = `group3`). I want to highlight the labels in the graph with different colors based on the group they belong to.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (50,50))
im = ax.imshow(matrix)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(keys)))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(keys)))
ax.set_xticklabels(keys)
ax.set_yticklabels(keys)

plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")

fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, shrink = 0.3, pad = 0.02)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of the same length as the keys, with the corresponding group id's, you can loop simultaneously through the ticks and the groups, and assign a corresponding color.

Here is some example code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

keys = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
groups = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
colors = {1: 'navy', 2: 'crimson', 3: 'limegreen'}
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 10))
im = ax.imshow(pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 6)).corr(), cmap='inferno', aspect='equal')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(keys)))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(keys)))
ax.set_xticklabels(keys, size=20)
ax.set_yticklabels(keys, size=20)

plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90, ha="right", rotation_mode="anchor")

for xtick, ytick, group in zip(ax.get_xticklabels(), ax.get_yticklabels(), groups):
    xtick.set_color(colors[group])
    ytick.set_color(colors[group])

fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, shrink=0.3, pad=0.02)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you! I managed to solve the problem!